# Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

I want to display some of name on tableview cell which is stored in postFromFriends array but when i wrote this code which is shown below its give me an error of " Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String' " on declaration of name constant. If anyone can help.Thanx

```
var postsFromFriends = [String]()
```

This is my array for appending the name.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! FriendsTaskTableViewCell

    if let name = postsFromFriends[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String {
        cell.name?.text = name
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please include the definition of `postsFromFriends` array

Comment: I did check my edited question @SohilR.Memon

Comment: And how you add data into it?

Comment: postsFromFriends[indexPath.row] will return you a string obviously.

Comment: Simply getting my data from json and appending to postFromFriends @SohilR.Memon

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `postsFromFriends` as an array of `String`, but it sounds like you want an array of dictionary:

```
var postsFromFriends = [[String:String]]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your error message that `postsFromFriends` is an array of `String`s, then `postsFromFriends[indexPath.row]` returns a `String`, which you're then trying to subscript with `["name"]`. Did you perhaps intend your `postsFromFriends` array to store Dictionaries, or some custom object type that has a subscriptable name field?

Comment: I did, created an array to store dictionary in that dictionary I have name object.